# Find the orthogonal projection of the given vector on the given subspace $W$ of the inner product space $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

$V=\mathbb R^2,u=(2,6),  $ and $W={\{(x,y):y=4x}\}$.

I've no idea about how to get through this. Please help in understanding this in detail,if possible pictorial representation will  be best.

Comment: Well, $W$ is spanned by $\displaystyle\left\{ {4\choose 1}\right\}$. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : You have that the vectors in W are written as $(x,4x) \Leftrightarrow x(1,4)$ That means that every vector in W is a linear combination of $(1,4)$ which is mathematically written as $ W= span[(1,4)]$. From this, you should be able to easily find what you asked.

Comment: :Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Charalampos Filippatos for the hint.
[image]

Comment: I gave it a quick glimpse because I am doing multiple stuff now but it seems okay. Did you check the answers through something too ?

Comment: @Charalampos Fliippatos:Yeah,it is correct.Thank You!!

Comment: @Charalampos Fliippatos:Can it have multiple answers?

Comment: Great, yep seemed correct. What do you mean multiple answers ?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos:I mean ,the solutions to such kind of problems are UNIQUE?

Comment: Yes, orthogonality with respect to a specific example gives a unique return. It's not like a vector defined by a linear combination that there are infinite combinations. The orthogonal basis that you start from is made with respect to the span of the starting base.

Comment: By the way remember to approve my answer if it was helpful for you so that the thread goes down as answered .